# Symfony: how to create api to authenticate Users?

Tags: rest, symfony, authentication, mobile, token

I want to create an API REST in Symfony that allows mobile application can access. Normaly we have **session/cookie** in browser communicate between browser and symfony (php) to know user connecting.

But in mobile application (ios, android), we don't have session/cookie. **How to authenticate users and identify user connecting in every request in Symfony ?**
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use an authentication key:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html